# how to disable mouse/mouse clicks inside a web Browser control?

Tags: vb.net, webbrowser-control

I am creating my personal DVR program instead of using the one in the package.
my problem is, I want to disable the mouse because whenever I click it in the camera feed (webBrowser control), it enlarges/zooms and it overflows the fixed size of the form I want.
can I disable that? so it will stay to the size that I want.

I already used this

```
web.IsWebBrowserContextMenuEnabled = False
web.AllowWebBrowserDrop = False
```

I have put it in Form_Load, it does disable the clicks.. but after i click it once..
help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if the following does what you're after:

```
CType(web, System.Windows.Forms.Control).Enabled = False
```

Comment: thanks a lot, sometimes, it is really better to ask than search through a lot of codes lol